# Changing Values in MYSQL By Clicking on Text?

Tags: php, mysql, message

I'm working on a small little social network project. So far i have a message system that all works fine, users can send and receive messages. I'm looking for a way to let users delete their own messages.

A 'delete' row has been set to display down the side of each message through an echo command.
Is there a way to make this text clickable so that when a user clicks it this then changes the value in the database from '0' to '1'?

Code:

```
<?php
$page_title = "Messages";
include('includes/header.php');     
confirm_logged_in();
include('includes/mod_login/login_form.php');
?>

<div class="modtitle">
    <div class="modtitle-text">Inbox</div>
</div>

<div class="modcontent">

<strong>Inbox</strong> | <a href="messages_sent.php">Sent Messages</a>
| <a href="messages_deleted.php">Deleted</a> <br /><br />
 <table
width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr
bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <td width="30%"><strong>Recieved</strong></td>
    <td width="20%"><strong>From</strong></td>
    <td width="28%"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
    <td width="0%"><strong>Read/Unread</strong></td>
    <td width="0%"><strong>Delete</strong></td>
</tr>


<?php
    $inbox_set = get_inbox();
    while ($inbox =
mysql_fetch_array($inbox_set)) {
             ?>

<?php  if ($inbox['read'] == 0) { ?>   <tr bgcolor="#6666B3"> <?php } 
if ($inbox['read'] == 1) { ?>   <tr>

<?php }  ?>



    <td><?php 

            $datesent1 = $inbox['date_sent'];
            echo "$datesent1"; ?></td>


    <a href="profile.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}"><td><?php echo "<a
href=\"profile.php?id={$inbox['from_user_id']}\">{$inbox['display_name']}";
?></td></a>

    <td><?php echo "<strong><a href=\"read_message.php?msg={$inbox[0]}\">{$inbox['subject']}</a></strong>";
?></td>

    <td><?php   if ($inbox['read'] == 0)  {
                echo "Unread"; 
                }
                if ($inbox['read'] == 1)  {
                echo "Read";
                }
                ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                if ($inbox['delete'] == 0)  {
                echo "Delete"; 


                }
                 if ($inbox['delete'] == 1)  {
                echo "$deleted_set;";
                }   


                    ; ?></td>


                </td>
        <?php }


?>

</tr> </table>



</div>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: I would recommend doing this with ajax, so send the info to the ajax ile and onsucces you can delete the message.

Comment: great sample would be in here... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: hey, ok thanks Jonathan, i'm still learning php and ajax, so i'm afraid i don't have a clue what code to use or where to put it. can you let me know what i need to put in and where please?

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX request to trigger proper action on server side.

Remember to check authorization otherwise one may delete messages owned by other users.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery + Ajax to do this task similar like this

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url, // action page url
        data: "id="+id,
        success: function(msg){
        if(msg) {
              //action here     
        }
    });
```